# Resistors in para and series circuit, finding volt

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

[image]

How anyone know how to do the question? I know how to reduce it to a window pane of 6/6/6/6 with a 3 in series but i have no idea how to do it.

Well i did manage to reduce the right side of the circuit to a pane of 6/6/6/6 and am unable to determine if its a Wye-Delta transformation (probably not) and I do not know which of the resistors are in parallel and which are in series.

Answer should be 4/3V

(The website which the answer was hosted initially no longer exists)

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE! Please refer to the Help page for tips and links to further tips about how to write a good homework question. As it is, this question is likely to be closed since questions that ask us to solve homework problems are off-topic

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if im wrong

The circuit can be reduced to

[image]

Current should be I = V/R = 4/3V

The voltage drop across the 6 resistor is 6/9 * 12 = 8    and the voltage drop over the 3 should be 12-8 = 4

Then we look at the circuit again

[image]

The Voltage drop across each 'section' of parallel resistors is the same. So  V across the 8 and 4 is 4.

To calculate Vo which is the voltage drop across the 4 resistor:

Ro / (Rtotal)   * V =   4/12  * 4 = 4/3V

Comment: Are you sure the answer is 4/3?  I obtained 5/3.  It is entirely feasible that I made a mistake some where though.

Comment: Do explain how you arrived at 5/3 though? Like which resistors you took to be in parallel/series